# trigger (ngOnChange) by code to bind the changed model value

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have an input field that takes a date and use pipe to change the output accordingly and with that I am using

```
(ngOnChange)="myvalye=myFunction($event)"
```

to update the value. now I have a button whose onclick i want to reset all the data. Below is the code for refrence.

```
<mydatepicker [ngModel]="mydate | datepipe" (ngModelChange)="mydate=myFun()"/></mydatepicker>
<button class="btn btn-default"  (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
```

so on click of reset button myValue is not getting changed in input box.

datepicker library can be found [here](https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker)

Comment: What happens if you assign the value of mydate in myFun() as opposed to returning the value?

My hunch is that myFun() is reevaluated on the change and the value reset.

Comment: sorry. It is working fine for input type="text". I was asking for datepicker tool. I have updated the question